# How to set up bridged networking in Xen?

Tags: network-bridge, xen

I have 2 domU virtual machines installed on a 11.10 Oneiric Dom0. My internal network is on the 192.168.1 subnet, and when the domU's start, they get ips on the 192.168.122 subnet. I have attempted to follow the instructions here : http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Xen_Networking

xend-config.sxp is configured correctly, but neither of my domU's have a config file in /etc/xen to modify. ifconfig reports that I have the following devices :

eth0, lo, tap3.0, vif3.0, vif4.0, virbr0

bridge-utils is installed. I also just attempted to follow these steps :

https://serverfault.com/questions/233201/bringing-the-xenbr0-interface-up-on-xen-under-ubuntu-8-04

```
sudo brctl addbr xenbr0
sudo brctl addif xenbr0 vif3.0
device vif3.0 is already a member of a bridge; can't enslave it to bridge xenbr0.
```

Any ideas on next steps are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue boiled down to 2 items:

- establishing a bridged network interface (xenbr0), and
- learning how to configure existing domU's which did not have configuration files.

---

**Establishing a bridged network interface (`xenbr0`)**:

Compiling information from [here](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Host_Configuration/Networking).

1. added the following to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

   ```
   auto xenbr0
   iface xenbr0
   bridge_ports eth0
   bridge_stp on
   bridge_maxwait 0
   bridge_fd 0
   ```
2. simply restarting networking didn't do the trick, but restarting the machine and running `ifconfig` returned :

   ```
   xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:e5:49:e6:bd:e2  
             inet addr:192.168.1.111  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
   ```

   `brctl show` returned :

   ```
   bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
   virbr0      8000.000000000000   yes     
   xenbr0      8000.50e549e6bde2   yes     eth0
   tap4.0
   vif3.0
   vif4.0
   ```

   The key here being the **eth0** listed as an interface for `xenbr0`.

---

Once `xenbr0` is configured, we can configure the domU's to use it as their interface.

Using method 2 found [here](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3466408) :

- Export the virtual machines configuration
  `xm list -l SLES10 > sles10` where "SLES10" is your domU's name
- Backup the file sles10, you may need it in the event that something is corrupted.
- Open the file sles10 for editing
- Locate the line reading

  ```
  (bridge virbr0)
  ```
- Change it to

  ```
  (bridge eth0)
  ```
- Save the file
- Reimport the new configuration

  ```
  xm new -F sles10
  ```

  Upon restart, both domU's are now on the 192.168.1 subnet.